# Is there any harm in creating and aborting a thread in ASP.NET via Response.End()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make a COM call and only want to wait x seconds for the call to return. If the call does not return in x seconds, I want to end the request.

Create a `Thread` to make the call.

```
string output = null;
Thread t = new Thread(() => { output = SomeHelper.DoWork(); });
t.Start();
t.Join(timeout);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))                
     this.Send500();
```

Method that ends the response.

```
protected void Send500()
{
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Status = "500 ServiceUnavailable";
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Response.Flush();
    Response.SuppressContent = true;
    Response.End();
}
```

When `Response.End()` fires I get a `Thread was being aborted` error. This is expected. I'm fine with the error. It's OK for what I'm trying to do.

Is there other cause for concern when this error is returned that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Well, you're leaving that task to go along continuing to do work.  If it keeps on going forever, or for a very long time, and this happens over and over, it could eat up all of your server's system resources.  Aborting the current thread doesn't abort that other thread.

Comment: Do you mean I need to call `Thread.Abort()` to make sure it aborts the child thread?

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx

Comment: @PaulT. No.  even if you did, it wouldn't help.  The COM object can just ignore the thread abort.

Comment: @PaulT., so currently you're not calling `Thread.Abort` anywhere, are you?

Comment: @noseratio I'm not calling `Thread.Abort`. I'm not certain if I need to? Or `Response.End` kills the child thread.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Thread.Abort is very evil, but aborting the own thread is safe. Aborting a thread is dangerous because the abort can happen between any two instructions. But aborting the own thread happens at a well-defined point. That makes the consequences predictable.

You are not aborting the thread that is performing the work that could time out. This is good because it would be a non-cooperative abort. You risk that many background threads accumulate and exhaust some resource. But if that risk is tolerable you're fine. If it is not tolerable, wrap the invocation to the COM service in a `Semaphore` like synchronization region to bound the maximum resource usage.

I'd say that your use of `Response.Flush` is questionable because it is rarely necessary to flush bytes to the client. This looks like a superstitious `Flush` to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there other cause for concern when this error is returned that I
>   need to be aware of?

Your main response thread gets aborted by ASP.NET (refer to the [`Response.End` implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpResponse.cs#4a66c734706db954)). The `t` thread you've started for your COM object remains active, for as long as `SomeHelper.DoWork()` returns or the `AppDomain` of your web app gets recycled. Whether this is a problem or not depends on what's going on inside `DoWork()`, but in the long run it may hurt your server scalability, at least.

Even if you called `t.Abort()` (which is never a good idea), the `t` thread will not be aborted until the unmanaged call returns.

I'd rather move `SomeHelper.DoWork()` to a separate process, which can be easily killed/re-launched, as long as there's no other way to cancel this call gracefully. Perhaps, the easiest way to implement this would be to make your COM object out-of-proc by registering a helper [DLL Server for Surrogate Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You may need a helper "factory" COM object to create `SomeHelper` and kill the surrogate host process if needed.